# HID lagging - dongled keyboard

Tags: 19.04

I am new to Ubuntu 19.04, but not new to Ubuntu as a whole. I wiped a 27 inch iMac (Mid 2011) a friend snagged in a college auction, and it's worked just fine as an Ubuntu machine- today I attempted to write using my trusted Microsoft bluetooth touchpad + keyboard. It skips keypresses terribly when I'm writing at length. If I type slowly, it's fine.

First, I changed the batteries in the keyboard. When that didn't fix the problem, I used a different USB port. Next, I checked the Accessibility settings. Then I checked to see if it could 'see' it's RAM- I thought next that the graphics driver was wrong, and it isn't (it's using Radeon BARTS, but CAYMAN also is listed for the Radeon 6970). Next, I tried Googling "Ubuntu 19.04 laggy", and ended up here.

It's a massive improvement over OSX Lion, even with the input lag. And it's all in one case is very sleek on my desk... But if I can't use it for lengthy text, it's useless to me.

Comment: Does a wired keyboard suffer from the same issue?